# Bitmap or Image file - get the filename

Tags: c#, image

Is there anyway at all to return the filename of the image , or the path or some useful meta data like this.

It seems as though as soon as you create an image object you loose any information like that.

Thanks

Comment: How are you loading the image?

Comment: Image g = new Bitmap("singleFile.png", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How data is stored is not a property of the data itself. This is the same for images; you can store the *same* image at *different* locations, so it is impossible to return *the* filename. Instead, you can wrap your image in an `LocationBoundImage` class or something like that, where you keep a reference to the image and the filename by yourself.